# WebStorm debug javascript stopped and disconnected so fast

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm (8.0.4) in a Mac (Mavericks last version). I'm trying to debug this simple loop for script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var i=0;i<10; i++)
        {
            console.log('hola!');
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using Chrome with JB Extension with this configuration:

> Host: 127.0.0.1  Port: 63342

In the settings of the Project, in Javascript, Debugger I have this configuration:

> Built-in server port: 63342

The code STOP in the breakpoint (in the loop for), but after one second, I have a message that says:

```
Disconnected (browser disconnected)
```

and I lost the debug mode...

I'm very lost and I don't know what happens... any help please?

Regards

Comment: I don't know the tool, anyway it's kinda normal that loop ends in few m-secs so you probably need something to block and read the console, like an alter("Stop"); after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Debugging stopped after 1 second

Two things I changed:

- Downloaded the latest version of WebStorm (8.05)
- Before the debug opened the configuration and looked at all pages and save it.

After this, it just worked again.

Comment: Thanks, update solve my problem... but it's curious because I checked for updates yesterday... Regards!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by Chrome update.
Chrome API changes in versions 37+ have made it incompatible with WebStorm debugger. [WEB-12418](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12418) is fixed in [WebStorm 8.0.5](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/) and [WebStorm 9 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP).

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm 7 so I guess no debugging for me unless I buy the latest version.

Comment: yes - you have to either buy a new version or downgrade Chrome:(